# How to call a flet function by symbol or string?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

How to call a flet function by symbol or string?

```
((lambda (s) (flet ((fn1 (x) x)) (funcall s))) 'fn1)
```

and

```
((lambda (s) (flet ((fn1 (x) x)) (funcall s))) "fn1")
```

I know the above codes don't work because funcall needs a symbol, but I don't know how to get that symbol created inside a flet or let.

Comment: Are you actually trying to look things up in the lexical scope or are you unfamiliar with `#'`? Specifically that if you replaced `'fn1` or `"fn1"` with `#'fn1` your code would work?

Comment: @DanRobertson: it won't work, since the (function fn1) would not be in the scope of the flet...

Comment: @RainerJoswig ah thanks. I didn’t read the code carefully enough to notice the weird structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer has two parts:

- why you can't do this;
- why you can do this if you want to.

In both parts I've not talked about why doing this sort of thing is terrible style, since it lets you ask questions, from outside, about the implementation details of functions: it should be no concern of anyone but the function what names it binds in its implementation.

### Why you can't do this

I think it's worth thinking about why what you're trying to do really makes no sense.  Here's your code with indentation to make it easier to read:

```
((lambda (s)
   (flet ((fn1 (x)
            x))
     (funcall s))
 'fn1)
```

So what this is doing is calling the function `(lambda (s) ...)` with an argument of the symbol `fn1`.  The function then tries to call whatever this symbol denotes as a function, and you expect this should be the function defined by the `flet`.

OK, so let's consider something similar but without the whole local function thing

```
((lambda (s)
   (let ((g 1))
     (??? s))
   'g))
```

So, the intention here is that this should return `1`, because the function should be able to look up the value of the local binding for `g` *by name*.

Well, there are two questions here:

- what should the operator I called `???` be?
- what would be the implications of this if it worked?

What should `???` be?  Well, clearly, it can't be a global function in a lexically-scoped language.  So we'd need either for it to be bound as a local function (there is precedent for this in CL: `call-next-method` is like this), or for it to be a new special operator in the language: in either case I'll call this thing `vbv` (for 'variable binding value').  That operator does not exist in CL, by the way.

What would the implications for the language be if `vbv` existed?  Not good.  For instance consider this function:

```
(defun lookup (s)
  (let* ((x 1)
         (y (f x)))
    (vbv s)))
```

Two things are apparent: this function has no idea what `s` is.  So the function is restricted in two ways:

- it has to maintain a table mapping symbols to bindings so `vbv` can work;
- the binding of `x` can't be compiled away.

This means that compilers for a language which had this operator would, in cases where it was used, necessarily suck.  The only saving grace is that, since `vbv` can't be a global function it's possible to tell at compile time whether you have to do all this extra work or not: you can't do something like

```
((lambda (f s) 
   (let ((x 1))
     (funcall f s)))
 #'vbv 'x)
```

which would make the whole situation completely hopeless. But that in turn is horrible: anyone who wants to write a compiler for such a language, and wants that compiler to produce good code, has to almost write *two* compilers: one crappy one which gets used for code where `vbv` appears, and one good one which gets used where it doesn't.  No-one wants to be forced to do that.

So that's why `vbv` does not exist.

But local functions are just the same: I could invent another operator, `fbv` which gets at the locally-bound function-value of some symbol, and that has all the same problems that `vbv` does:

- it can't be a global function (so, in particular, `funcall` or `apply` can't do this, because they are global functions);
- its implications for the performance of code which uses it are horrible.

### Why you can do this, if you want to

Well, this is Lisp: it's the *programmable* programming language.  So of course, if you want to, you can do this.

Here is a simple-minded version of a macro called `named-labels` which is like `labels` but maintains names.  It is simple-minded because the local `fbv` function that this defines only looks at its own names, so nesting this does not work the way it should.  To make that work I think you probably need a code-walker.

```
(defun fbv (name)
  ;; function-binding-value, global version
  (declare (ignore name))
  (error "no bindings"))

(defmacro named-labels (fbindings &body code)
  ;; like LABELS but make FBV work in the body for things we've
  ;; defined.
  (let ((stash-name (make-symbol "NAMED-LABELS-STASH")))
    `(let ((,stash-name '()))
       (labels ,fbindings
         ,@(loop for fb in fbindings
                 for n = (car fb)
                 collect `(push (cons ',n  (function ,n)) ,stash-name))
         (flet ((fbv (name)
                  (let ((found (assoc name ,stash-name)))
                    (if found
                        (cdr found)
                      (error "no binding for ~S" name)))))
           ,@code)))))
```

And now

```
> (funcall ((lambda (s)
              (named-labels ((fn1 (x) x))
                (fbv s)))
            'fn1)
           2)
2
```

Note that looking at the expansion of `named-labels` will show you why having the system do this for you by default would suck.

Comment: very good, before ask me, I don't want do nothing with the code, I just like have fun with the language and see until where I can go. I was have fun with the possibles implementations of OOP, there are many ways

Answer (score 4):

> *How to call a flet function by symbol or string?*

You cannot; a *flet* function is a lexical binding, not a dynamic association between a symbol and a function. *flet* function bindings are named by a symbol, but that association isn't in a global environment, and can disappear when the code is compiled.

If we have a function like this:

```
(lambda (s) (flet ((fn1 (x) x)) (funcall s)))
```

the inner `fn1` is an hidden, encapsulated implementation detail that outsiders aren't supposed to know about.

It's best to treat it that way and think of a solution which doesn't require the caller to know about `fn1`.

An anonymous function which dispatches inner function seems like an anti-pattern; we can just capture multiple lambdas:

```
(let (v1 v2 ...)   
  (flet ((fn1 (x) ...) (fn2 (x) ...))
    (vector #'fn1 #'fn2)))
```

Now if we want to call `fn2`, we take the returned vector and `(funcall (aref vec 1) arg)`. That vector itself provides the dispatch mechanism into multiple operations that share the same captured lexical environment.

What we are doing is reinventing OOP in a bad way; we should be probably be using structures or objects.

Comment: For do by this way. Would be simpler like this: `((lambda (s arg) (let ((l (list 'fn1 (lambda(x) x)))) (funcall (getf l s) arg))) 'fn1 7)`

Comment: @PerduGames  Any lookup structure will serve for dispatch: hash table, vector, assoc list, property list. Not sure  a property list is simpler than a vector. A vector doesn't index on arbitrary symbols, but its direct access can be considered simple.

Comment: I can be wrong, but if you develop your code until answer the proposite question you can see why I say that plist here is "simpler" than vector.

Answer (score 3):

There is no default mapping from symbols to lexical bound functions. Common Lisp does not provide that.

One needs to do something like:

```
CL-USER 212 > ((lambda (s arg)
                 (flet ((fn1 (x) x))
                   (case s
                     (fn1 (fn1 arg)))))

               'fn1
               42)
42
```

Comment: Not like that. XD if what I want to avoid is the use of the conditional.

Comment: @PerduGames: there is no way to retrieve a lexical function otherwise. The code needs to do it.

Comment: why? how are they created?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience the names of inner functions created by `flet` and `labels` should not matter for anything but the defining functions:

```
(defun create-adder (x)
  (flet ((add (y) (+ x y)))
    ;; only this function CREATE-ADDER needs to know
    ;; that the flet is named ADD.
    #'add))

(setq f (create-adder 3))
> #<Interpreted Closure (flet create-adder add) @ #x100208cf302>
```

It does not matter that the flet is called `add`.
The important thing is that it is a function (closure) you can `funcall`:

```
(funcall f 2)
> 5
```

You can create a different closure based on a parameter:

```
(defun create-adder (kind)
   (flet ((add-1 (x) (+ x 1))
          (add-2 (x) (+ x 2)))
      (ecase kind
         (1 #'add-1)
         (2 #'add-2))))

(create-adder 1)
> #<Interpreted Closure (flet create-adder add-1) @ #x10020903c52>

(create-adder 2)
> #<Interpreted Closure (flet create-adder add-2) @ #x10020902862>
```